# iphone - change view with button programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I read this [tutorial](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-using-storyboards-in-xcode-4-2/) about storyboards on iphone dev. The guy changes views through a button. But the connection of the button is made through the interface builder. How can i do this programmatically, so i can make some checks (username/password for example) before the view is changed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect one view with other (not the button with the view).
Change the segue to custom and give it an identifier (in IB). Ex: Login

Then create an action and assign it to the button.

In the button action use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
```

Create a Segue Class object and in the .m use something like:

```
UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
UIViewController *nav = [self sourceViewController];

//All your custom code

[nav presentModalViewController:dst animated:YES];
```

Edit: Forgot something important!

In IB, in the Segue configuratión, put in Segue Class, the name of the Segue Class created. Ex: LoginSegue is the name of the segue created, in Segue Class yo has to write "LoginSegue"

Edit: To Create the Class:

1.- Create a New File extending UIStoryBoardSegue, the .h gonna be something like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoginSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

2.- In the implementation, use the code above inside an method called perform:

```
-(void)perform
{

UIViewController *dst = [self destinationViewController];
UIViewController *nav = [self sourceViewController];

 //Custom Code

 [nav presentModalViewController:dst animated:YES];

}
```

If you need to access the property of the source viewController, you need to change:

```
UIViewController *nav = [self sourceViewController];
```

to

```
eYourClass *nav = [self sourceViewController];
```

Hope this help!

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by saying "Create a Segue Class"?

Comment: A class that extend of UIStoryBoardSegue. Gonna edit the answer to add it

Comment: i see that i have to overide the perform method. Any clues how i should do it?
(btw i use a navigation controller - i dont want to use modal)

Comment: call the moethod to push instead present form nav.

Comment: mate you just saved my skin.
thnaks a lot xD

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the button and drag the touchUpInside action to an `IBAction` in interface builder

or in code somewhere in `viewDidLoad`

```
  [self.login addTarget:self action:@selector(loginTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then the `loginTapped` method could look something like

```
- (void)loginTapped;
{
  if ([self authenticateWithUsername:self.username.text password:self.password.text]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccessful" sender:self];
  } else {
    // Warn user about invalid username/password
  }
}
```

This relies on you having created the segue in the storyboard with a name that matches the `identifier` argument